# Reading large shapefile in R using using sf package

Tags: r, shapefile, r-sf

I have a shapefile of points with 32M observations. I want to load it in R and I have tried read_sf and st_read but my R session keeps getting crashed. One other way that came to my mind was to write a for loop, subsetting columns that I want and maybe going a specific number of rows at a time and then rbinding them, but cannot figure out how to make R understand the query. Here's what I have so far which is not working:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
  j = i-1
  jj = i+1
  print(i)
  print(j)
  print(jj)
  A <- read_sf("C:\\Users\\...parcels-20210802T125336Z-001\\parcels\\join_L3_Mad_Addresses.shp", query = "SELECT FID, CENTROID_I, LOC_ID FROM join_L3_Mad_Addresses WHERE FID < "jj" AND FID > "j"")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can readapt the following code.

Load packages

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.0, GDAL 3.2.1, PROJ 7.2.1
```

Define path to a shapefile

```r
dsn <- system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")
```

Count the number of features in `dsn`

```r
st_layers(dsn, do_count = TRUE)
#> Driver: ESRI Shapefile 
#> Available layers:
#>   layer_name geometry_type features fields
#> 1         nc       Polygon      100     14
```

Start a for loop to read 10 features at a time. Add the data to a list

```r
shp_data_list <- list()
i <- 1
for (offset in seq(10, 100, by = 10)) {
  query <- paste0("SELECT * FROM nc LIMIT ", 10, " OFFSET ", offset - 10)
  shp_data_list[[i]] <- st_read(dsn, query = query, quiet = TRUE)
  gc(verbose = FALSE)
  i <- i + 1
}
```

Rbind the objects

```r
shp_data <- do.call(rbind, shp_data_list)
```

Add an ID column (just for plotting)

```r
shp_data$ID <- as.character(rep(1:10, each = 10))
plot(shp_data["ID"])
```

[image]

The only problem is that this process may not preserve the geometry type. For
example,

```r
unique(st_geometry_type(shp_data))
#> [1] MULTIPOLYGON POLYGON     
#> 18 Levels: GEOMETRY POINT LINESTRING POLYGON MULTIPOINT ... TRIANGLE
```

while

```r
unique(st_geometry_type(st_read(dsn, quiet = TRUE)))
#> [1] MULTIPOLYGON
#> 18 Levels: GEOMETRY POINT LINESTRING POLYGON MULTIPOINT ... TRIANGLE
```

You can change the geometry type with `st_cast()`

<sup>Created on 2021-08-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>